# Ansible AWX workflow

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I am new to ansible and AWX. Making good progress with my project but am getting stuck with one part and hoping you guys can help.

I have a Workflow Template as follows

1. Deploy VM
2. Get IP of the VM Deployed & create a temp host configuration
3. Change the deployed machine hostname

Where I am getting stuck is once I create the hostname when the next template kicks off the hostname group is missing. I assume this is because of some sort of runspace. How do I move this information around? I need this as later on I want to get into more complicated flows.

What I have so far:

1.

```
 - name: Deploy VM from Template
      hosts: xenservers
      tasks:
       - name: Deploy VM
         shell: xe vm-install new-name-label="{{ vm_name }}" template="{{ vm_template }}"
       - name: Start VM  
         shell: xe vm-start vm="{{ vm_name }}"
```

2. 

```
---
- name: Get VM IP
  hosts: xenservers
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: Get IP
      shell: xe vm-list name-label="{{ vm_name }}" params=networks | grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | head -1
      register: vm_ip
      until: vm_ip.stdout != ""
      retries: 15
      delay: 5
```

Here I was setting the hosts and this works locally to the template but when it moves on it fails. I tried this in a task and a play.

```
- name: Add host to group 
      add_host:
      name: "{{ vm_ip.stdout }}"
      groups: deploy_vm
        - hosts: deploy_vm
```

3. 

```
- name: Set hosts
  hosts: deployed_vm
  tasks:
     - name: Set a hostname
       hostname:
        name: "{{ vm_name }}"
       when: ansible_distribution == 'Rocky Linux'
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you can achieve this with the `set_stats` module: https://arctiq.ca/2020/03/26/transferring-state-in-an-ansible-workflow/.

Comment: I will test, I was trying with set_fact to a global variable but that was not working. This might be what I need. Ill update.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and I have that passed across now and working. Thanks very much!